# How many Tzadikim from Moshe Rabbeinu until today have brought the Shekinah down one level through their merit?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu

This question is based on the Basi Legani, which discussed the topic of seven Tzadikim who each have brought the Shekinah down from one level of heaven to another.

The text states that Moshe Rabbeinu merited the giving of the Torah because he was the seventh Tzadikim and the seventh is cherished unto G-d.

I would like to know how many Tzadikim from Moshe Rabbeinu until now merited the same "lowering of the Shekinah" down one heaven.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Maximo and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Once the Shechina has come down, it is down, so none. Some in  Chabad claim their Rebbeim did so, but that is part of why they are so controversial.

Comment: So the Shekinah is hovering over the face of the waters as we speak?

Comment: You seem to be referencing the verses in the beginning of Genesis. Whatever that is referring to, it meant on that day of creation, before G-d split the waters, etc. The Shechina is currently in our world.